# MSYS install PyQt5 module

Tags: python, pyqt5, mingw, msys

I am trying to install some modules in MSYS (Python 3.8.7)

For example i install PyQt5 using the following command:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5
```

The module is installed correct (there are files in `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages`) but when i am trying to import it (from PyQt5 import QtCore) no module found error.

I also tried with pip but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i did that:

1.

```
pacman -Qqn | pacman -S -
```

The above command reinstall all the installed packages.

2. I run python interpreter not from MSYS2 MSYS application but from MSYS2 MinGW 64 bit application.